# Using vlookup to return a formula works except the formula will only use the first row in the table for the variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, boolean, vlookup

This is my first time using booleans and trying to vlookup to return a formula. I have been using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656304/is-it-possible-to-use-vlookup-to-return-a-formula) and [this method](http://exceltovba.com/vlookup-evaluate-function-returning-formulas-instead-values/) to get excel to use vlookup to return a formula. I've tried it both with and without a table. It works for the first row, but after that the formulas keep referring to the fields in the first row for every other formula.

I recreated the spreadsheet with generic names [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjxxTr-E1JMlj0bMr3i7mT02w0gq?e=sTHZkO) if people want to actually see the formulas in action (Please excuse the rawness of it).

The lookup formula I'm using is `=eval(VLOOKUP([@[Boolean Only]],Sheet2!$C$3:$D$9,2,0))`

The formulas that it should be choosing from are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VjoW.jpg) if you want to look. The first row picks up the formula `BlueTable[HIRE_END_DATE]-BlueTable[HIRE_START_DATE]` (I've tried both with and without @ before the column name. If I use the @s, it returns #NAME error)

[image]

End result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRYvh.jpg). When the formula has been picked up, it uses the first row, not the row of the formula.

[image]

I've tried both

```
Function Eval(s As String) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Application.Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

and

```
Function EvalFormula(FormulaCell As String)
EvalFormula = Evaluate(FormulaCell)
End Function
```

The second was suggested in other posts on the internet, but made no difference.

Have I missed something? I just can't work out how to get it to change the row for the formula. It doesn't need to be a table, if that helps. I only did it to match up with what I read. Any assistance would be appreciated!

*For anyone who wants some exposition on what I'm doing, the boolean works out what formula to use to find out how many days the item was on hire during user specified dates (The actual file is >50,000 rows over the entire year). So if, say, the item is still on hire, the resulting formula will use the end date specified by the user and minus the start date of the hire to get the number of days. There's a little more to it but I just want to find out why the vlookup isn't working before I put the rest of it in.*

Comment: Hi RainbowCanary, Can't really tell due truncation of the data, but guessing that you're not getting a solid hit on your vlookup...Try filtering UNIQUE on table's 'Boolean Only' field (bottom image), Then  copy & physically match-up your lookup table against just the UNIQ's and compare column value to column value. Also since your target lookup appears small (just an assumption for the example), you might try using sorting this table on the lookup (C3) value) and modifying the vlookup call to exact (True => ",2,0" chg to ",2,1").

Comment: Hi JBowman, Apologies I must have missed the notification of your reply. Thanks for giving it a go, but it turns out it was just the computer/excel being moody. Came in Monday morning and it worked as-is. Very frustrating given I probably spent over 2 hours trying to get it to work that Friday!